# On Notification Mechanisms in MathOverflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications, users

Inbox is where a typical user receives most notifications in Mathoverflow. One also receives moderators' private messages through mail. My question is:

> What other notification mechanisms are available in Mathoverflow? For example is it possible to track the questions, comments and answers of a particular user who posts interesting topics in your favorite field? Is there something like a "follow" button for users which exists in most Q&A sites? Is it possible to receive the new questions and answers of a particular user via mail? (It is currently available to receive activities on a particular post via mail).

Comment: As a general SE feature, one can "favor" questions; see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work. But no plans for an actual *notification* system for this are in sight.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Yes. I'm aware of both "favorite" and "notification via mail" features in a post. What I'm looking for is a mechanism for following the entire contribution of a particular user in the site who often makes good points, without any need to check the "activity" section in their profile. Something like receiving a mail when they post something that is possibly of your interest. Why there is no "follow" button in one's profile when all other similar Q&A sites have such a feature? Is there any reason behind this?

Answer (score 7):

This request comes up frequently but it is "status-declined" on the general meta (then meta SO) [A "friends list" on Stack Overflow would be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/a-friends-list-on-stack-overflow-would-be-nice)

The main reason given then was:

> SO is not a social networking site.

Then there were few other sites and no MO yet, but the reason extends.
One is not really supposed to follow by *user*, and for example focusing ones voting on some few users too much could even cause problems.
Instead, one can follow by *subject*, viz. a tag.

There are non-official extensions though that allow some such things see https://stackapps.com/questions/3535/stack-exchange-favorite-users and https://stackapps.com/questions/1863/follow-your-friends-on-stackoverflow-with-friendoverflow for example (I did not try them though)

Also see the "opposite" request on this meta [Ignoring certain users' postings](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/555/ignoring-certain-users-postings)

Comment: "focusing ones voting on some few users too much could even cause problems"  Could, and often does. Targeted voting is a frequent nuisance, and unpleasant to have to rectify through vote invalidation.