# Blocking things from feed

Tags: feature-request, spam

Is it possible to block certain users or tags from appearing on one’s personal feed?

Comment: Tags, yes. Just ignore them and change the setting to hide ignored tags. For users, no.

Comment: A related older posts: [Ignoring certain users' postings](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/555). Asaf Karagila mentioned ignored tags - you can find link to the FAQ [in the corresponding tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/ignored-tags/info).